# How to hide css border-right using loop for even number count in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp and here is my sample code below along with the css i am doing

```
<div class="thumbs">
    <?php if(!empty($auction['Product']['Image']) && count($auction['Product']['Image']) > 0):?>
        <?php foreach($auction['Product']['Image'] as $image):?>
            <?php if(!empty($image['ImageDefault'])) : ?>
                <span><?php 
                    echo $html->link(
                        $html->image('default_images/'.$appConfigurations['serverName'].'/thumbs/'.$image['ImageDefault']['image']), 
                        '/img/'.$appConfigurations['currency'].'/default_images/max/'.$image['ImageDefault']['image'], 
                        array('class' => 'productImageThumb'), 
                        null, 
                        false);?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>

.thumbs span //css for how to display the images
{
    float:left;
    width:75px; //this displays two images as a thumbnail in a single row
    margin:12px;
    border-right:1px solid #d5d5d5;
    padding:3px;
}
```

My problem is i want to do css `border-right:none` for all the images having count as even numbers. I tried using for loop in the `span` of my code but not getting the result. Please suggest me how to dynamically do css `border-right` for only thumb images of odd number count and not for even numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the key to the foreach loop and add a new class to odd images using the key (assuming this is a standard Cake query result where the key reliably increments by one):

```
foreach( $auction['Product']['Image'] as $key => $image ):
    $odd = ( $key % 2 ) ? ' oddImage' : '';
    ....
        array( 'class' => 'productImageThumb'.$odd ), 
    ....

.oddImage {
    border-right:1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
```

(Protip: You don't have to wrap every line of PHP into `<?php ... ?>` tags. The code will be much more readable if you close the PHP tags only when you need to output pure HTML.)

Comment: Thanks juhana and i will change as you told